# Py{} adds a none in the code

Tags: pythontex

I have the following MWE using pythontex:

```
%& -shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\newcommand{\printPython}[1]{
\py{print(r'Hello, #1')}%
\newline
}
\begin{document}

Say hello Python:

%\begin{python}%
%print r"Hello \LaTeX!"
%\end{python}%
\printPython{4}
\begin{pycode}

print(r"\centering")
print(r"\textit{A message from Python!}")
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

When compiling, the result is

```
Say hello Python:
Hello, 4 None
A message from Python!
```

Where does the `None` come from, and how do I remove it?

Comment: I solved it by replacing `\py` with `\pyc`, but nevertheless I am interested in the reason here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\py` inserts a string representation of whatever it is given. In this case, it was given the `print()` function, which returns `None`. So you get what was printed, *plus* the return value. Basically, `\py` is a shortcut so that using `print()` isn't necessary.  You could just use `\py{r'Hello, #1'}%`.

`\pyc` is the inline equivalent of the `pycode` environment. It just executes code. So if you want it to insert anything in the document, you need to use `print()`.